# Insert PDF To my MSSQL Database

Tags: php, sql-server, image, upload, insert

i wanna Insert my PDF from $_FILES into my MSSQL Database(ERP system).
So if i insert this i get following Error Message from the SQL Server:
102 if i write if i write down :Dokument near the Cast and if i set it too ':Dokument' near the Cast then i get this error Type 002 (null) [0] (severity 0) [(null)]

```
                $filetemppath = $_FILES["_NDAUPLOAD"]["tmp_name"];
                $filename = $_FILES["_NDAUPLOAD"]["name"];
                $filesize = $_FILES["_NDAUPLOAD"]["size"]; 

                $extract = fopen($filetemppath, 'r');
                $content = fread($extract, $filesize);
                    // Überprüfe Upload
                    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                        $filename = addslashes($filename);
                        $content = addslashes($content);
                    }
                fclose($extract);

                $docsql = "INSERT INTO DOKUMENT (Typ, Dateiname, Dokument, JournalID) VALUES (2, :Dateiname, (Cast (:Dokument AS varbinary(max))), NEWID()))";                  
                $d = $db->prepare($docsql);
                $d->bindParam(':Dateiname', $filename);
                $d->bindParam(':Dokument', $content);

                $de = $d->execute();
```

Comment: I hate to tell you but that is pretty much NOT a SQL problem as much as likely a PHP(?) problem - your code is wrong and you do not even tell us what language you use ;) Retag please

Comment: upload file to server using move_uploaded_file() then save the path and file name in db... you can't literally save the image in database....

Comment: @JayakarthikAppasamy Its not an Image its an PDF File and i need to store the file content in the Database

Comment: you can save pdf just like image... saving pdf in db is gonna cost a lot of memory....

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i need it as an PDF File its for my ERP system. So you have any idea?

Comment: you want to upload pdf to server or to save in db field??

Comment: to save the file content (-> $content ) correctly into my Database not the file @JayakarthikAppasamy

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Chkout this...